# String serialization in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, serialization, binary

I have a following class fields:

```
int _number; 
string _name; 
int _amount;  
bool _isAvailable; 
double _price; 
int _storageTime; 

int _entranceDay; 
int _entranceMonth;
int _entranceYear;
```

How shall I serialize/deserialize an object of that class?

I tried this:

```
    void Serialize() {
        ofstream ofs("tmp.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
        ofs.write((char*)& _number, sizeof(int));
        ofs.write((char*)& _amount, sizeof(int));
        ofs.write((char*)& _isAvailable, sizeof(bool));
        ofs.write((char*)& _price, sizeof(double));
        ofs.write((char*)& _storageTime, sizeof(int));
        ofs.write((char*)& _entranceDay, sizeof(int));
        ofs.write((char*)& _entranceMonth, sizeof(int));
        ofs.write((char*)& _entranceYear, sizeof(int));
        int stringSize = _name.size();
        ofs.write((char*)& stringSize, sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; ++i) {
            char c = _name[i];
            ofs.write(&c, sizeof(char));
        }
        ofs.close();
    }
```

And this for Deserialization:

```
    void Deserialize() {
        ifstream ifs("tmp.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
        ifs.read((char*)& _number, sizeof(int));
        ifs.read((char*)& _amount, sizeof(int));
        ifs.read((char*)& _isAvailable, sizeof(bool));
        ifs.read((char*)& _price, sizeof(double));
        ifs.read((char*)& _storageTime, sizeof(int));
        ifs.read((char*)& _entranceDay, sizeof(int));
        ifs.read((char*)& _entranceMonth, sizeof(int));
        ifs.read((char*)& _entranceYear, sizeof(int));
        int stringSize;
        ifs.read((char*)& stringSize, sizeof(string));
        string name;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; ++i) {
            char c;
            ifs.read(&c, sizeof(char));
            name += c;
        }
        _name = name;
        ifs.close();
    }
```

Serialization doesn't throw any exception. As for deserialization - it throws an exception: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ifs' was corrupted." 
Debugger shows, that all the fields were deserialized correct expect for the string field.
So, how to serialize/deserialize a string correctly?

Comment: On a few other notes, your serialization isn't portable. The size of e.g. `int` is not fixed, and neither is its [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The `double` type is also not portable, it's binary representation is not specified by C++, it's typically hardware dependent. And as `int`, the size of `bool` is not specified. What *is* specified is that `sizeof(char)` will *always* be equal to `1`, no matter the actual number of bits used for it.

Comment: Both your serialization and deserialization code for the string could be simplified: You know the length and the number of elements to write and read, so write and read them all in one go. For the writing side just do `ofs.write(_name.data(), _name.size());`, and on the reading size, do e.g. `_name.resize(size); ifs.read(_name.data(), _name.size());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Deserialize

> ```
> ifs.read((char*)& stringSize, sizeof(string));
> ```

must be

```
ifs.read((char*)& stringSize, sizeof(int));
```

However note the compiler/byte order/etc must be the same when you serialize and deserialize, why are you not using standard external representation of number/string/... ?

Note also by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1